# modernizr 3d transform not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, modernizr, flip

I'm create and web template with this, but after done I seen this not working on google chrome.

Demo:
http://www.queness.com/resources/html/css3dflip/index.html

and my chrome Version 37.0.2062.3 dev-m

how I can fix it on chrome?

Comment: I'm running Version 35.0.1916.153, working pretty fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the version of your Chrome you're using uses the unprefixed CSS properties like transform, transition etc rather than -webkit-transition. I'm using v38.0.2094.0 Canary and I can replicate what you're seeing.

The problem comes because your CSS has the wrong property values inside the `.thumb.flip .thumb-wrapper` selector:

`transition: -moz-transform 1s;` should be `transition: transform 1s;` and the same for the `-o` and `-ms` prefixes (not that I think you need `-ms`).